# Why does it take longer to import a function from a module than the entire module itself?

Tags: python, performance, python-import, python-internals

Consider:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('from win32com.client import Dispatch', number=100000)
0.18883283882571789
>>> timeit.timeit('import win32com.client', number=100000)
0.1275979248277963
```

It takes significantly longer to import only the Dispatch function rather than the entire module, which seems counter intuitive. Could someone explain why the overhead for taking a single function is so bad? Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's because:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
```

is equivalent to:

```
import win32com.client              #import the whole module first
Dispatch = win32com.client.Dispatch #assign the required attributes to global variables
del win32com                        #remove the reference to module object
```

---

But `from win32com.client import Dispatch` has its own advantages, for example if you're using `win32com.client.Dispatch` multiple times in your code then it's better to assign it to a variable, so that number of lookups can be reduced. Otherwise each call to `win32com.client.Dispatch()` will first search search for `win32com` and then `client` inside `win32com`, and finally `Dispatch` inside `win32com.client`.

---

**Byte-code comparison:**

From the byte code it is clear that number of steps required for `from os.path import splitext`  are greater than the simple `import`.

```
>>> def func1():
    from os.path import splitext
...     
>>> def func2():
    import os.path
...     
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(func1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (('splitext',))
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (os.path)
              9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (splitext)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (splitext)
             15 POP_TOP             
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(func2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (os.path)
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (os)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

**Module caching:**

Note that after `from os.path import splitext` you can still access the `os` module using `sys.modules` because python caches the imported modules.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules):

> Note For efficiency reasons, each module is only imported once per
>   interpreter session. Therefore, if you change your modules, you must
>   restart the interpreter – or, if it’s just one module you want to test
>   interactively, use `reload()`, e.g. `reload(modulename)`.

**Demo:**

```
import sys
from os.path import splitext
try:
    print os
except NameError:
    print "os not found"
try:
    print os.path
except NameError:
    print "os.path is not found"

print sys.modules['os']
```

**output:**

```
os not found
os.path is not found
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
```

**Timing comparisons:**

```
$ python -m timeit -n 1 'from os.path import splitext'
1 loops, best of 3: 5.01 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -n 1 'import os.path'
1 loops, best of 3: 4.05 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -n 1 'from os import path'
1 loops, best of 3: 5.01 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -n 1 'import os'
1 loops, best of 3: 2.86 usec per loop
```

Comment: I like this answer better!

Comment: It awesome an answer -- includes: *concept*, *practical-proof*, and *doc-standard*. Best answer like anyone can get.

Comment: I don't think this answer gets to the point.  The OP is assuming that the execution time of an import statement is dominated by actually importing the module.  This assumption is generally true, but the OP is measuring this time in a wrong way, and this answer details why you get the observed result when measuring this way.  The much more important point that the OP isn't measuring what he thinks he is measuring is missing.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Did a test using timeit's command line interface for a single loop, normal import is still faster.

Comment: With only one loop, the timeit results are rather noisy and meaningless.  Try running this for a few times -- I'd be pretty sure this is not reproducible predictably.  Moreover, your answer wouldn't give an explanation for a timing difference of 1 µs -- the few dictionary manipulation would take a fraction of a ns on a modern machine.

Comment: @ashwch I really appreciate your knowledge in python. Do you have your book or any blog. If yes please let me know. My email - jain01ankur@gmail.com

Comment: @Workonphp Nop, sorry.

Comment: @ashwch Please write one, and I think soon you will become a famous python book writer :).

Answer (score 12):

The entire module still has to be imported to get the name you want from it...You'll also find that the OS is caching the module so subsequent access to the `.pyc` file will be quicker.

Comment: I guess follow up question, the entire module can be cached, but does python also catch functions from modules?

Comment: @JonClements: Not just parsed, but imported. After `from foo import bar`, look at `sys.modules['foo']`, and you'll see the exact same thing as if you'd done `import foo`.

Comment: @TheoretiCAL: What do you mean by that comment? The function is just an object with a few attributes, one of which is some bytecode. There's no need to cache that; it's just a thing you can copy around like anything else. The _name_ could be cached, but… to where? It's already in `globals()`, so caching it to `globals()` isn't going to help…

Comment: @abarnert thanks - not quite sure why I wrote parsed - my original draft had *imported* - this is what happens when it gets late ;)

Comment: @JonClements: Don't worry; I think we all imported your answer correctly anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that your code isn't timing what you think it is timing.  `timieit.timeit()` will run the `import` statement in a loop, 100000 times, but at most the first iteration will actually perform the import.  All other iterations simply look up the module in `sys.modules`, look up the name `Dispatch` in the module's globals and add this name to the importing module's globals.  So it's essentially only dictionary operations, and small variations in the byte code will become visible since there relative influence compared to the very cheap dictionary operations is big.

If, on the other hand, you measure the time it takes to actually import the module, you can't see any difference between the two approaches, since in both cases this time is completely dominated by the actual import, and the differences fiddling around with the name dictionary become negligable.  We can force reimports by deleting the module from `sys.modules` in each iteration:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: %timeit from os import path; del sys.modules["os"]
1000 loops, best of 3: 248 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit import os.path; del sys.modules["os"]
1000 loops, best of 3: 248 us per loop

In [4]: %timeit from os import path
1000000 loops, best of 3: 706 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit import os.path
1000000 loops, best of 3: 444 ns per loop
```

Comment: I just realized the first import only will actually perform the import as well, making the example in my question somewhat misleading. Thanks for pointing out how that results in the times being roughly the same.